# When building for iPhone Simulator, link error for OS 10.6?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I imported a project from XCode 3 to 4 and I've picked up an unusual error.  I probably changed a setting without realizing it since I'm still getting used to the new layout.  I'm getting a link error when building for the simulator:

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

It looks to me like XCode is trying to link using the 10.6 libraries, rather than the iPhone simulator.  Any idea where the setting is?

BTW, building for a device works just fine.  So it's annoying but not a show-stopper.

Comment: A screen-cap of your Architecture build settings would be helpful here.

Comment: Here it is [link](http://goo.gl/Yve9G).  Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: After playing around with this, the moral of the story is always uninstall XCode 3 completely before installing 4.  My project files kept getting hosed up while I was importing data.  Finally, I ripped out the development tools completely and installed from scratch.  It worked perfectly after that.  All I had to do was bump the iOS SDKs in my projects to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your project is mis-configured to use the MacOS SDK. Go to your project properties. Go to build settings. Set the "Base SDK" to the "Latest iOS".

Comment: I've played around with it and that doesn't seem to work.  I'm wondering if its an Xcode 3 bug I'm carrying over.  (Like the mysterious /Skiing/... volume that my project is trying to link against.)  If I delete the target and re-create it, it works fine.  It's just a royal pain.